Can someone please solve this question I think it is 3 but answer scheme says that is wrong

My reasoning for the option 3 is that the ratio of amino acids to carbons is more than 2 is to 1 and the ratio of amino acids to nitrogens is greater than 1 is to 1 and that is the only correct choice with these criteria

The question asks you to choose 2 options. Please [edit] and show us the second you have chosen and explain your reasoning for choosing that one.

Yes I am aware but I do not see another possible option using nitrogen and carbon ratio method

Welcome to SE Biology. Please finish reading the [Tour] to find out how this site works. There are two general problems with your question in this respect. First your title should not be a “please help me” request but an indication of the biological subject matter that your problem relates to. This helps readers decide whether to read a question, and allows indexing. Second, we discourage posting text as graphics, as this discriminates against the visually impaired. It may seem a chore, but questions should be typed out.

I'll answer this on https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com this is probably the wrong site, hence despite my attempts to upvote you - its been downvoted
